# What is best method to read a column value having quote ' and insert into a different table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hey I have a name column in my table, suppose i get have name O'Neil, when ever i read this name and insert into a linked server throught dynamic SQL I get error...How to handle this...
One method is to check if my name has a quote(') but I am researching if someone coul

my dynamic SQL looks like 
'name = '+@quote+@name+@quote

@quote is nothing but below...
set @quote = ''''

thanks,
Naga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you problem could be demonstrated with this code:

```
declare @Name varchar(20)
set @Name = 'O''Neil'
declare @SQL nvarchar(100)
set @SQL = 'select '+@Name
exec (@SQL)
```

Result: `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Neil'.`

You can use [quotename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to properly add quote characters:

```
set @SQL = 'select '+quotename(@Name, '''')
```

The better alternative is to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) and pass `@Name` as a parameter.

```
set @SQL = 'select @Name'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Name varchar(20)', @Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PreparedStatements then this is better way of inserting/updating many rows. Such code in Jython (using Javas JDBC) looks like:

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc_url, usr, passwd)
pstm = db.prepareStatement("insert into test (lastname) values (?)")
pstm.setString(1, "O'Neil")
reccnt = pstm.execute()
```

You will find similar PreparedStatement in ODBC, .net etc. It should be much lighter for database for massive inserts then creating full SQL insert statement for every inserted value.

Such massive insert from CSV file can look like:

```
pstm = db.prepareStatement("insert into test (lastname) values (?)")
while not csvfile.eof():
    lastname = csvfile.next_line()[0]
    pstm.setString(1, lastname)
    reccnt = pstm.execute()
```